# srcUp method functionality

Tags: service-cloud-console

Recently I came across a script to open a visualforce page in Salesforce Console and found the use of function srcUP(). Could you please let me know what exaclty does this function do and is a part of which library.

Comment: Did you checked this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YKxYAAW

Answer (score 2):

Yes SrcUp can be used to open subtabs in service cloud console.

here is an example of JS in button to open a VF page in console.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")} 
if(typeof(srcUp) == 'function') //Checks that it is in console
{ 
var openSubtab = function(result){ 
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/apex/YourVFPageName?caseID={!Case.Id}&inConsole=true', true, 'Subtab Name', null); 
}; 
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab); 

} 
else{ 
window.parent.location.href=('/apex/YourVFPageName?caseID={!Case.Id}&inConsole=false') 
}
```

This Button code will handle opening of VF page in console and outside console very effectively.

Answer (score 0):

srcUp is a method that allows you to open new subtabs when in the `Salesforce.com domain`, like “`na1.salesforce.com`”. Visualforce pages are served from the Visualforce domain, like “`c.visual.force.com`”. Visualforce pages don’t have access to the `srcUp` method, and hence need the Service Cloud Integration Toolkit methods to open new subtabs/ primary tabs.

Source - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YKxYAAW

As per this [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29041/javascript-execution-on-button-click-with-service-cloud-console) the following scripts are required.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/xdomain/xdomain.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")}
```