# VF page Displayed in console vs Displayed in classic

Tags: visualforce, console, sidebar, header

I have a VF page which needs to be displayed in the Console as subtab. The header and sidebar should not be displayed in the console. 
However I need the header and sidebar to show up if this page was accessed in Classic as tab.
I’m using a custom button to call the page.

I don’t know how to determine if the page is being invoked in a console or differently so that the header and sidebar can be displayed accordingly?

**VF to set subtab:**

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/26.0/integration.js"/> 
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function(){
               testOpenSubtab();
            };  
    function testOpenSubtab() {
        //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    };
     var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result){
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.setTabTitle("{!$objectType.ExpressOrder__c.label}");
    }; 
        </script>
```

**My custom button with &isdtp=vw:**

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/28.0/integration.js")} 
var url = "/apex/VF013_Create_Express_Order?id={!Account.Id}&isdtp=vw"; 
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
srcUp(url); 
}else { 
window.open(url,'_self'); 
}
```

[image: with &isdtp=vw]

**My button without &isdtp=vw:**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/28.0/integration.js")}
var url = "/apex/VF013_Create_Express_Order?id={!Account.Id}";
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
srcUp(url);
}else {
window.open(url,'_self');
```

[image: withouth &isdtp=vw]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this : [Thanks to Nishant Singh Panwar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92851/srcup-method-functionality/116350)

**Code below :**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")}
if(typeof(srcUp) == 'function') //Checks that it is in console
{
var openSubtab = function(result){
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/apex/VF013_Create_Express_Order?id=
{!Account.Id}&inConsole=true', true, 'Subtab Name', null);
};
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
}
else{
window.parent.location.href=('/apex/VF013_Create_Express_Order?id=
{!Account.Id}&inConsole=false')
}
```

The job is done. I would have liked to use the 'var url'